# 2 ways of adding an object to $scope, only one works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a user-service taking care of the authentication.

In the html I have:

```
<div ng-show="user.authenticated">Hi {{user.username}}!</div>
```

The controller sets up the scope like this:

```
$scope.user = userService;
```

This works great! If I am reloading the html-page, the div is hidden for a short while until the already logged in user is authenticated.

But if I try to set up the user-object on $scope in the controller like this:

```
$scope.user = {
  username: userService.username,
  authenticated: userService.authenticated
};
```

If I reload the page, then it does not work any more, the div is never shown, even if the user already is logged in, like in the above example. How this is not working?

**Edit:** I will add the controller (or at least, the part of the controller that is interesting here):

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
  .controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope','$location','userService','alertService',
   function($scope,$rootScope,$location,userService,alertService) {
//    $scope.user = userService;  // This works (but is now commented out)

// The following does not work if the user reloads this page
// The view is only updated with username when (after a few milliseconds)
// userService has talked with the server and gotten the user-details...    
      $scope.user = {
          username: userService.username,
          authenticated: userService.authenticated
        };

   }]);
```

It is important to reload the html after login, or else the userService will already be set up with the user-details. So when the view is set up (after page-reload), there is no user-info available in the userService, this is available only a short while after reload....

**Edit 2:** The reason I was trying the second variant is because I have a page with an object with various properties and the username is only one of those properties needed. This works fine until the user possibly reloads the page.

**Edit 3:** I have altered 2ooom's fiddle to make it more my case, see http://jsfiddle.net/utphjuzy/1/

Comment: Can you please mention where you setting the $scope.user?? Set this on page loads also.

Comment: In the controller I am setting $scope.user. I am testing it the same controller, I am just commenting out one variant, so the only thing that changes is how I set $scope.user... One works, the other not. What do you mean by "set this on page loads also"?

Comment: You cant do like this $scope.user = {
  username: userService.username,
  authenticated: userService.authenticated
};

Comment: @Archana, ok, I can live with that, but why?

Comment: The last snippet wil have the authenticated property always set to false or undefined; wrap it into a function.

Comment: Please kindly refer this http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app

Comment: @Archana, my problem is not with authentication, my first option works fine. I am curious why my second option did not work. I tried quickly browse the link you gave, but I did not see any comment on this. Maybe I missed it?

Comment: @EricC, Can you please share your detailed controller code?

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha, there is no errors, the thing is that in the first variant, changes in the userService get propagated to $scope.user successfully (when the user is authenticated and set up with info on the user), but in the second variant, this is never propagated to $scope.user (and therefore the view is not updated, no error, just no result...).

Comment: @EricC Did you actually check if the `user` object assignment is being executed. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uoqaozbe/) works flawlessly for me

Comment: @EricC, How did you declare/initialize the $scope.user object?

Comment: @Archana, I included the controller in the question... Did this answer your init-question?

Comment: @2ooom, the problem is that the userService is "empty" when you reload the page (after login). It takes a few milliseconds for the userService to get connected with the server and get hold of the user-details. In your fiddle, this is instantly ready as fixed values...

Comment: @EricC So you answered your own question... first case works because you are assigning the reference of userService, so whenever it get connected values are added in scope. 2nd option is just simple value assignment. I think you have to initialize the scope at `onsuccess` event of userService?

Comment: @anuragal, do you have code example for that?

Comment: @EricC: I tried this
      $scope.user = {
          username: 'sdfsdf',
          authenticated: true
        };Its working fine.So the problem is in userService return object Please confirm whether your userService returning the data or not

Comment: @Archana, as I wrote 2ooom:  the problem is that the userService is "empty" when you reload the page (after login). It takes a few milliseconds for the userService to get connected with the server and get hold of the user-details. In your example, this is instantly ready as fixed values...

Comment: @EricC I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e59me6o/1/) as an example. First assigned userService to scope then updated userService object that makes scope change.

Comment: @EricC: Then you have to handle this case by template caching.

Comment: @Archana, I am not sure if I understand you. The problem is that the $scope.user.username and $scope.user.authenticated are not updated when userService has updated info on those (from the server). Or, tell me more on this solution.

Comment: @anuragal, I altered your fiddle to show my problem... http://jsfiddle.net/utphjuzy/ See?

Comment: @EricC Not able to find what changes you did to the fiddle :-(

Comment: Sorry, @anuragal, forgot to update fiddle, here is the correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/utphjuzy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This as to do with how Angular's binding mechanism works (and how *binding* works in general).

When you do something like `$scope.user = userService;`, you are actually binding the property `user` to the **Object** `userService`. That means that both properties will point to the same in-memory mutable object reference. If a property of that object changes, then both "pointers" will notice that change (in the case of the `$scope.user`, that will force a re-render).

However, if you use it like this:

```
$scope.user = {
  username: userService.username,
  authenticated: userService.authenticated
};
```

You are creating a completely new `user` **Object** and you are assigning its properties **not by reference but by value** because JavaScript strings, numbers and booleans are immutable and therefore cannot be assigned by reference. Ultimately this means Angular will not be able to track changes on those properties.

One way of doing what you need is to use a *model* **Object** on the service that holds any data that needs to be bind. Like shown in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QzoDqHC0XnHWMgbFKxjd?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for explaining **why**, and of course for the solution @bmleite :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting values which will never be updated.  Your controller only runs once so this:

```
  $scope.user = {
      username: userService.username,
      authenticated: userService.authenticated
    };
```

gets set to whatever values they had when the controller was created.  Since I'm guessing your user service gets the details using AJAX, it will never update the user object on your scope.

Answer (score 0):

**Why this works?**

```
$scope.user = userService;
```

here userService object is directly assigned to scope, so all updates on `userService` object after assigning it to scope variable will reflect into scope. for e.g

```
var userService = {};
$scope.user = userService;
alert($scope.user.username);
angular.extend(userService, {"username":"User"});
alert($scope.user.username);
```

So in above example `$scope.user.username` will have value `User` in the last statement

**Why this doesn't work?**

```
$scope.user = {
  username: userService.username,
  authenticated: userService.authenticated
};
```

here values are extracted from `userService` and assigned to scope, so future changes to `userService` will not be reflected into scope. That's why `$scope.user.username` will be `undefined`

Created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e59me6o/1/) for explaining the same

**Solution**

In my opinion you should initialise / re-initialize the `$scope.user` on `success` event of `userService` call.